# Append javascript to existing drupal block preprocess

Tags: drupal-7

I am using the [DFP Drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/dfp) for our display advertising tags. I would like to append an additional piece of JavaScript provided by another module to each DFP block with preprocess. Is that possible? i want to avoid doing it via Theme.

Answer (score 1):

To add js in your preprocess function make use of `drupal_add_js`, for more details see this [link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the following code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {

    $block_id = $vars['block']->module . '-' . $vars['block']->delta;
    // Use the following to inspect the ids of the active blocks in a given page
    drupal_set_message($block_id);

    switch ($block_id) {
    case 'block-12': // block id of the target
        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/css/my-block.css');
        break;
    }
}
```